# Intellisense while editing JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I am creating project in Visual Studio. While editing JS in a HTML file, since we have included the reference to all JQuery files on top, we get intellisense for jquery instances. But, when we are editing JS files, we don't get any intellisense at all! Is there any way to get intellisense there too?

Comment: What platform are you editing in? Eclipse? NetBeans? Visual Studio?

Comment: Is this about VisualStudio specifically?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder My answer was accepted so I guess the question was about Visual Studio, after all. I've re-added the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Visual Studio, try adding the following line to the top of your .js file.

```
/// <reference path="~/path/to/your/jquery.js"/>
```

Also, if you're using anything other than the version of jQuery that was packaged with Visual Studio, you'll need a `jquery-x.x.x-vsdoc.js` file that matches your jquery filename, and put that vsdoc in the same directory as your jQuery library.

(For example, if you are using `jquery-1.5.2.min.js`, you will want `jquery-1.5.2-vsdoc.js` in the same directory of your project)

You can get the applicable vsdoc file at this page:

http://appendto.com/community/jquery-vsdoc

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be implying that you are using Visual Studio to edit your JS files. If so, perhaps the [JScript Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed) extension for VS would work for you. It adds support for Intellisense inside JS files.