# Where can I find an Intellisense documentation file for JQuery 1.11.3

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I have read in several places that I need a `jquery-1.*.*-vsdoc.js` file to make Intellisense recognise JQuery extensions. I am writing an MVC project in Visual Studio 2013.

I can't seem to find `jquery-1.11.3-vsdoc.js` on http://jquery.com/ or through Google searches, can someone point me in the direction of this file?

There is a link on another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852395/intellisense-while-editing-js-files) but it is now broken

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use NuGet?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery-vsdoc/

It should be available in the GUI directly as well if you do not like the CLI.